How to insert pagination in wordpress tag.php?
I'm building a theme from scratch and I ran into a problem. When trying to add pagination to my tag file, it appears but when I click the button it goes to a page not found. I will inform my codes
Note: I already clicked on the permanent links, changed the custom structure to %postname% and %category%
I already clicked on the permanent links, changed the custom structure to %postname% and %category%
I tried to insert the same pagination that exists in my archive
Tag
<?php
get_header();
?>
    <?php set_query_var('parameter1', 'img-service-page'); get_template_part('parts/fifith/tag');?>
    
        <h1>Tag: <?= get_query_var('tag')?></h1>
        
            <?php 
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'notices',
                'tag' => get_query_var('tag'),
                'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1
            ); 
            $custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
            if ($custom_query->have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php while ($custom_query->have_posts()) :
                    $custom_query->the_post();
                    get_template_part('parts/news-card');
                endwhile; ?>
            <?php else : get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'none'); endif; wp_reset_postdata();?>
<?php
get_footer();
?>

archive-notices
<?php
get_header();
?\>

<?php set_query_var('parameter1', 'img-service-page'); get_template_part('parts/fifith/navigation-blog');?>

        <?php
        $posts_per_page = 9;
        $args = array('post_type' => 'notices', 'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page, 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1);
        $var = new WP_Query($args);
        if($var->have_posts()):?>
            
                <?php while($var->have_posts()): $var->the_post();                                                               
                    get_template_part('parts/news-card');
                endwhile; ?>
            
            <?php $big = 999999999;
            $pagination = paginate_links(array(
                'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
                'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
                'total' => $var->max_num_pages,
                'type' => 'list',
                'prev_text' => __('« Anterior'),
                'next_text' => __('Próximo »'),
            ));
            if ($pagination): ?>
                
                    <?php echo $pagination; ?>
                
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php
get_footer();
?>

custom-post

$notice = array(
        'name'          => _x('Notices', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Service', 'post type singular name'),
        'menu_name'     => 'Notícias',
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'            => $notice,
        'description'       => 'Custom Post for notices',
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor','revisions', 'thumbnail'),
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-widgets-menus',
        'taxonomies'         => array('post_tag'),
    );
    register_post_type('notices', $args);```

<?php $big = 999999999;
$pagination = paginate_links(array(
'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
'format' => '?paged=%#%',
'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
'total' => $var->max_num_pages,
'type' => 'list',
'prev_text' => __('« Anterior'),
'next_text' => __('Próximo »'),
));
if ($pagination): ?>
<nav class="pagination">
<?php echo $pagination; ?>
</nav>
<?php endif; ?>


It looks like the issue with the pagination on the tag file arises from the way the pagination links are generated. It looks like the base URL for pagination might not be correctly formed for the tag archive. We should confirm that the pagination links are correctly set up to handle the tag archive URLs.
Specifically, ensure that the base parameter in paginate_links correctly reflects the tag base URL.
